# Python 3.3 - Need help writing a .png file with data from a .txt

Tags: python, hex

Using Python V.3.3

I was wondering how to create a .PNG (or any other picture file) by using hex data that was written in a notepad document. Currently it reads a picture file. From there it turns it into hex format then saves to a notepad document. It then reads the notepad file and grabs the data.

The problem I am having is that when it tries to write a new picture file it does, but there is no data stored. No matter what I try I end up with a blank, 0 byte picture. How do I fix this? Is there any specific format I need to use on my getbyte variable? Any help would be much appreciated. I'm trying to get this to work to possible send/store data easier for 2D game maps.

```
import binascii

f = open("c:/test1.png", "rb")
ima = f.read()
f.close()
print (binascii.hexlify(ima))

f = open("file123.txt", "w")
f.write(binascii.hexlify(ima).decode('utf-8'))
f.close()
#-----------
f = open("file123.txt", "r+")
getbyte = f.read()
f.close()

getbytes = (binascii.unhexlify(getbyte))
getbyte = (binascii.hexlify(getbytes))

f = open("filetest.png", "wb")
f.write(getbyte)
f.close

#-----------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save it as a binary image, write `getbytes`:

```
getbytes = (binascii.unhexlify(getbyte))
f = open("filetest.png", "wb")
f.write(getbytes)
f.close
```

I think you are also looking at the wrong directory, try to save under a different name and see if it creates that file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried the unhexlify version and still ends up as 0 bytes. Could this have something to do with the .decode()? As for the files, the script and files are located on my desktop. Only the first file used is in C:\

Comment: I just tried to follow the example with one of my own images (jpeg) and properly set paths. perreals hint to write getbytes was the solution!

Comment: comes up with something like this (i shortened) b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\'.

Comment: so it is not related to decode. can you try changing the last file to: `c:/filetest.png`?

Comment: I just tried setting the path directly to desktop, still didn't work. Could this possible be the result in using a non-admin acc on windows OS?

Comment: I can't save in C:/ access is denied, I'll try elevating this user to admin and see if that works

Comment: For some reason I can read data on C:/ but not create: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/filetest11.png'

Comment: I elevated this user to admin and it didn't work. I restarted the computer and retried, it works. I now have two identical files (byte wise) Thank you so much for your help. I was using notepad files for each map that held the tile data, this will help free up some much needed space and reduce lag. (16kb file vs a few hundred bytes)